# What value is required for the HTTP header Content-Type for Workday SOAP APIs?

Tags: http, soap, http-headers, postman, workday-api

I want to access data from Workday HCM using the APIs mentioned [here](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Human_Resources/v34.2/Human_Resources.html). Instead of using SoapUI or Zeep Python library, I want to try to fetch data using Postman as a part of a POC. I was curious to know what should be the value for the header **Content-Type** when I make a request using Postman ie whether it should be application/xml or text/xml. You may have a few questions that I have answered here:

Q1. Why can't I just try using application/xml and then text/xml?

A. I don't have an access to any Workday tenant to try it out.

Q2. Why do I need to know the Content-Type even before I have the tenant?

A. We already have a Postman type solution which lets a user to select either application/xml or application/json. Depending upon what Workday requires, I'll need to take further actions.

Q3. Both the Content-Type values are basically the same. How does it matter?

A. I know a few SOAP APIs fail when provided with Content-Type as application/xml instead of text/xml, hence the question. If Workday APIs respond successfully for both the types, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`application/xml`  and  `text/xml`  are  acceptable for the Workday SOAP API.

In fact, `Content-Type` in a request is not used at all by Workday. You can send `Content-Type: foo` and you will get your response.